# Newtonsoft Json.NET Ignore a member at runtime in Json converter or invoking JsonConverter SerializeObject

Tags: serialization, json.net, deserialization

Let's say I have the following custom JsonConverter for serialization and/or deserialization:

```
public class VersionConverter : JsonConverter<Version>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Version value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
    }

    public override Version ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Version existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string s = (string)reader.Value;

        return new Version(s);
    }
}

public class NuGetPackage
{
    public string PackageId { get; set; }
    public Version Version { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say I have the following code snippet in my application:

```
NuGetPackage p1 = new NuGetPackage
{
    PackageId = "Newtonsoft.Json",
    Version = new Version(10, 0, 4),
    Description = null
};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p1, Formatting.Indented, new VersionConverter());
```

I want the Json.NET converter to Ignore the Description member variable of the NuGetPackage class.

**Note: I do Not Want to use the following "marker boolean" member variable:**

```
public bool ShouldSerializeINSERT_YOUR_PROPERTY_NAME_HERE()
{
    if(someCondition){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

I would rather specify the ignoring of a specific member variable somewhere

a) when my code invokes the JsonConvert.SerializeObject?

b) or within the VersionConverter code class itself?

Could someone please show me how to ignore the specific member variable in such a way?

Comment: You can't cause `NuGetPackage.Description` to be skipped from within the converter for `NuGetPackage.Version`.  But if `NuGetPackage` is as simple as you show, you could just write a second converter for it.  (I'm assuming you can't modify `NuGetPackage`.)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on writing a 2nd converter for NuGetPackage?  Please show example code if possible :) Thx

Answer (score 2):

Since `NuGetPackage` is fairly simple, you could just write an additional `JsonConverter` for `NuGetPackage` that serializes only the members you need, e.g.:

```
public class SimplifiedNuGetPackageConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) { return objectType == typeof(NuGetPackage); }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var package = (NuGetPackage)value;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, new { package.PackageId, package.Version });
    }
}
```

Then serialize as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new VersionConverter() },
};
if (!someCondition)
    settings.Converters.Add(new SimplifiedNuGetPackageConverter());
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p1, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

If you are serializing multiple instances of `NuGetPackage` at once and need to write `Description` for some but not all, you could add the logic for `someCondition` inside `WriteJson()` itself:

```
public class ConditionalNuGetPackageConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) { return objectType == typeof(NuGetPackage); }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var package = (NuGetPackage)value;

        // Replace with your logic:
        var someCondition = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(package.Description);

        if (someCondition)
            serializer.Serialize(writer, new { package.PackageId, package.Version, package.Description });
        else
            serializer.Serialize(writer, new { package.PackageId, package.Version });
    }
}
```

And then serialize as follows:

```
var settings =  new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new ConditionalNuGetPackageConverter(), new VersionConverter() },
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p1, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Working .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4bh4Rs).

Comment: Note - I didn't use `JsonConverter<NuGetPackage>` only because https://dotnetfiddle.net doesn't support Json.NET version 11.